# Recruitment Process and Fixed Term Contract

Tags: work-environment, contracts, contractors

In my current role, I found out that I was the only person who wasn't offered a permanent role. But a fixed term contract. When I applied I was unaware that this was the case, but due to the circumstances I was in took this offer up on the contract basis.

As I have spoken to my fellow colleagues that was hired during the same period as me were given the option of being a permanent staff member and the other was offered permanent upfront.

What is the best way to get perm or should I start looking for another role? I have been in the position for roughly 3 months.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to get perm or should I start looking for another role?

The best way is to **speak to your manager**. Ask him/her why you were not offered a permanent position and if there is an option to move to a permanent position later.

People are usually offered a contract role because they either want the higher income and accept the risks associated with contracting or because the hiring company does not want the burden of too many employees. Since the OP did not request a contract, it sounds more like the latter. Therefore, I would stress your longer term benefit to your manager such as skills that others lack and/or your history of delivering successful projects.

If your manager does not give you satisfactory answers, then I would start looking for new roles, even just to help you bargain a better new contract if they offer it.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The contract is the same pay as a normal perm with all the benefits. But a contract length tacked on to it. Thanks you for your prompt response.

Comment: @JonSnow Thanks for the clarification. Nevertheless, I would still talk to your manager and ask why.